# Xcode Source Control showing multiple Working Copies

Tags: xcode, version-control

Xcode is showing multiple working copies:

```
Working Copies
myProject - master
myProject_olderRepo
myProject_originalRepo
```

The second two are greyed out.

The original code was cloned in Sourcetree from the repo of a previous owner. Not knowing how to move the files into a new repo, I simply copied locally the entire project directory, and started work on them.
Then I copied the contents of that reworked project directory into a folder linked to a repo to which others have access. When they clone the repo they get compile errors because modules (the two older repos) are missing.

I have almost no experience of source control and Bitbucket et al, so I humbly ask forgiveness for anything completely stupid that I am doing.

How do I remove those older working copies from Xcode's source control? Or is there some other way that others can then clone and compile the project without errors?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Solved this by deleting xccheckout file under

```
ProjectName.xcodeproj > project.xcworkspace > xcshareddata
```

This had contained references to the previous repos.

Comment: This solved the problem. Tough the directories where not exactly where you say

Comment: The only file I have under project.xcworkspace is contents.xcworkspacedata

Comment: same for me, don't have xcshareddata in project.xcworkspace

Comment: saved my all day !!

Answer (score 23):

I have removed old repo using following steps.

- ProjectName.xcodeproj -> Show Package Contents
- project.xcworkspace -> Show Package Contents
- xcshareddata
- Open .xcscmblueprint file using any text editor
- Remove all unrequited repo from following location
  DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintWorkingCopyRepositoryLocationsKey
  DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintWorkingCopyStatesKey
  DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintWorkingCopyPathsKey
  DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositoriesKey
- Save file and open Xcode again

Note : If your project have WorkSpace then Direct click on ProjectName.xcworkspace instead of ProjectName.xcodeproj

Comment: Don't have xcshareddata inside project.xcworkspace !

Comment: me neither, any ideas?

Comment: If your project have WorkSpace then Direct click on ProjectName.xcworkspace instead of ProjectName.xcodeproj

Comment: I have removed the .xcscmblueprint file and it worked

Answer (score 10):

I am using Cocoapods and have a .xcworkspace along with my .xcodeproj.

This is what worked for me:

1. Remove Cocoapods from the project using `pod deintegrate` in Terminal.
2. Run `pod clean`
3. Run `pod install` to create it again.

Now if you open the Workspace again, the other Working Copies should no longer exist.

Comment: Thank you. I had tried all the other approaches first and they didn't work. I guess using Cocoapods changes things.

Answer (score 4):

This solution helped me.
Go to terminal and paste below code (this will show hidden files)

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES.
```

Now go to your project folder and check if there is any .git files outside your working project folder.
[image]

.git file that is located outside project folder do not belong to your working project but other project. ( This is possible if you have made mistake in creating git for other project)

Either cut paste this .git file and save it some other location or you can delete it (if not so important). After deleting , reopen your project in xcode.

Comment: Two things. One, if you use that in terminal, you have to restart Finder for the changes to take effect.  But more importantly, while in finder, simply press COMMAND-SHIFT-PERIOD to toggle hidden files on and off.  No terminal needed. Enjoy! :)

Comment: Aha.. Thank you for the info :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have Git repositories showing up, then you must have a `*.xcscmblueprint` file somewhere in your project. For me, it was in my workspace and not in a project. From terminal window:

`% find . -name '*.xcscmblueprint'
./TaskMe.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/TaskMe.xcscmblueprint`

Edit that file with care to keep just the entry you want. Or perhaps better, just delete the file and add back the repository you want.

Comment: Deleting was the best option for me after messing around (for too long! lol) wi the xcscmblueprint file

Answer (score 1):

If this issue happens when using **CocoaPods** try:

- *Remove* myProject.xcworkspace
- *Remove* Pods/
- *Run* `pod install`

Answer (score 1):

Project.xcodeproj -> Show Package Contents

Project.xcworkspace -> Show Package Contents

xcshareddata

Open .xcscmblueprint file

Clean all content

Save file and open Xcode again

Answer (score 1):

You might have used other project files. (it happens when you drag files to XCode and you forget to checkmark 'copy items if needed').

checkout:
[Xcode git showing multiple repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55842282/xcode-git-showing-multiple-repositories)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what happened here, I had one project but two working copies, similar to question. One of the working copies was synced with a repo on GitHub, and I had successfully pushed changes there.
All I had to do, in the end, was to delete my local folder completely, then check out (clone?) from the remote repo on github again.

*(I'm not sure but I got the feeling that Xcode and/or the Xcode project was NOT handling multiple working copies, but that this was done like a top layer in the git structure itself. Maybe it is a feature of git?)*

Answer (score 0):

I had two instances of the same project in my ProjectNavigator in XCode. One of them was marked with M and the other one with ?

All I had to do to get rid of the copy, was delete the project marked with ? by control-clicking on it and selecting delete.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps:

```
1.  Open terminal and go to your project directory
2.  Run pod deintegrate in Terminal to remove Cocoapods from the project.
3.  Run pod clean
4.  Run pod install to create it again.
```

Open .xcworkspace, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had forked a project and the new fork was still pointing to the original project files, so I was seeing Git for both the new and the original project. To fix I did the following:

```
Project.xcworkspace -> Show Package Contents
contents.xcworkspacedata -> Change Path
```