# Xcode 7: Multiple working copies

Tags: xcode, version-control

I am trying to remove a Working Copy from an Xcode 7 project. Most of the suggested solutions involved the xcshareddata file, but since I don't have any shared schemes, I don't have this file.
I have deleted the git folder from the project folder, but I still see the unwanted Working Copy under > Source Control. 
One thing that I find puzzling is that Xcode won't let me commit changes (now that I have deleted the git folder, I assume). Perhaps this detail helps.

How do I remove all trace of source control, so that I can init a fresh git? Disabling source control in Xcode is not the answer, since I do indeed want to be using git. I just want to be rid of this working copy (that seems to come from a different project).

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all unrequited working copy using following linked steps.
 [Multiple Working Copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516220/xcode-source-control-showing-multiple-working-copies/35098590#35098590)

Comment: the link you provide is int he case you got xcshareddata file, but OP didn't have it