# Xcode: remove working copy

Tags: xcode, git

My git repo suddenly has two working copies in Xcode. It sends the commits to both the original working copy and a working copy that is actually my repository from a completely different project.

I have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516220/xcode-source-control-showing-multiple-working-copies) but there is no xcshareddata folder in my project.

How would I remove the wrong working copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently two files imported from the other project caused this to happen. To fix it I removed the files and imported them again by copying them to the project's folder.

Comment: how did you found those files imported from the other project?

Comment: Can't remember since it's been a while, but these files were never copied to the project folder. They were only added to the target. So maybe you could compare the files in your project folder to the files that are used in the project.