# Xcode making thousands of copies of app

Tags: ios, xcode, dropbox

I'm not sure what this problem is related to. I have an iOS app I have been working on for about a year in Xcode. It works beautifully when testing locally in simulator or on devices. I tried emailing the whole folder to a developer today and holy smokes! the app folder size is 29 GB!! So I investigate and see that the app is apparently creating copies of itself again and again inside folder after folder. Each folder has all the files of the app plus a folder that has the files of the app and so on....

It may be related to Dropbox as well, as I attempted to link the main app folder to Dropbox a while ago. I looked in my Dropbox account but there's only one folder there (with date modified not showing). 
I am afraid of breaking my app as well if I start deleting stuff, although I do think that the active one I am opening is the most top one when I go to the app in Xcode.

What could be causing this?

Please see attached screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please look this url  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516220/xcode-source-control-showing-multiple-working-copies/35098590#35098590

Comment: Thanks. None of those solution seem would work for me. I don't have folders in said locations as some others have commented on that question