# Xcode 9: Multiple Working Copies Git

Tags: xcode, git, xcode9, xcode9.2

I have Xcode 9.2 Version installed on my MacBook. Today when I tried to push new changes to my project, Git repo shows multiple working copies as shown in picture 1.

[image: Picture 1]

First one the actual working copies I have been using and the second one is an entirely different project in which I worked earlier. Whenever I try to push code to remote, it again shows those 2 working copies as shown in picture 2.

[image: Picture 2]

I tried to find the xcscmblueprint file and xccheckout file as mentioned in this **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516220/xcode-source-control-showing-multiple-working-copies)**.

I tried

- Cleared xcuserdata and xcshareddata folders
- removed current project and cloned a new copy
- Quit Xcode and restarted again
- Restarted my mac

Can someone help me to identify exact problem and methods to fix this?

Comment: any solutions on this? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Open Xcode -> click Preferences...

[image]

Now tap on `Location` tab then click on arrow same as below image
[image]

delete folder `DerivedData` and reopen your project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But clearing Derived data didn't help me.

Comment: It did help me. Thanks!