# Xcode shows multiple projects in source control

Tags: xcode, version-control, cocoapods

Recently, Xcode started showing two items in the source control tab: the first one is the main project I’m working on, and the second one is a pod I integrated (and it’s about the time I added the pod that I first noticed this thing).

[image: Xcode showing two items in source control]

I tried deintegrating CocoaPods, and after that the second repository disappeared from Xcode. But when I tried to only remove the single pod, the source control item was still there.

How do I remove the second repository from Xcode?

I use Xcode 10.1, and both items in source control are Git repos.

P.S. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516220/xcode-source-control-showing-multiple-working-copies) does not help.

Comment: this question needs to be a little less vague:  are you using `svn` and which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Yeah, thanks for pointing to that. I’ve added these details to the question.

Answer (score 4):

For me, deleting derived data folder fixed the issue.

Note: You can reach to derived data folder by using the path;

*Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations*